# Inconsistent preview and output of maths in spoiler blocks

Tags: bug, mathjax, spoilers

I was writing [an answer to a question on the main site](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1087112/24160), and using spoiler blocks as part of the answer. Several of the spoiler blocks include MathJaX with `$$` and the `align` environment.

In the editor preview, all the maths is shifted off to the left. In the rendered output, it's centre-aligned as maths in `$$` usually is. Here's a screenshot showing the difference:

[image]

Here's the source for that block (all squashed onto a single line for the needs of spoiler formatting):

```
>!$$\begin{align*}I\mathbf{x} &= \mathbf{x} \\H\mathbf{x} &= \alpha\left(\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{x}\right) \\H^2\mathbf{x} &= \alpha\left(\mathbf{n} \times \alpha\left(\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{x}\right)\right) \\&= \alpha^2 \left(\mathbf{n} \times \left(\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{x}\right)\right)  \\H^3\mathbf{x} &= -\alpha^3 \left(\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{x}\right) \\H^4\mathbf{x} &= -\alpha^4 \left(\mathbf{n} \times \left(\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{x}\right)\right)\end{align*}$$
```

I would expect the two renders to match; i.e., for it to be centre-aligned in the preview.

I'm using Safari 8.0.3 on the latest build of OS X Yosemite.

Comment: (This comment defines `\xx` and `\nn` so one can test the code given above. For whatever reason, I couldn't get `\cross` to work.) $\newcommand{\xx}{\mathbf{x}}\newcommand{\nn}{\mathbf{n}}$

Comment: @anorton: Oops, I forgot to copy the definitions over. I've updated the snippet so that you don't need those definitions. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Maybe you know or maybe you don't, but `\vec` is a pre-existing command. It's usually not a great idea to overwrite those, since it can mess up with other people's answers on the page (depending on the order of the answers, for example).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I did know that, but didn't consider it when writing that answer. I've swapped it out for `\myvec` instead.